# date parameter updated with time Anylogic

Tags: date, time, anylogic

I'm using Anylogic and I would like to assign a parameter of type date to each agent (agent is a customer), called DueDate, that represents deadline to his machine failure. My goal is to update value parameter and make it shorter as model time passes (because the failure date is coming). There is some function or code that I can use? I also want to assign a priority parameter to agent that increases when failure date is nearest, so that in queue a customer with a failure nearest is processed before agents with lower priority. How can I do?

Thanks at all

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to contradict itself somewhat. The parameter described is a *Due Date*, therefore, by definition, should be fixed. Yet, parameter value should be updated as failure date is coming. Do you mean that there should be two parameters: 1) *Due Date* and 2) remaining time until *Due Date*? If so this can be achieve like this:

1. Due Date - if you want to set due date at 10 time units after model start, you can make a parameter (call it `p_dueDate` of type ) and use `timeToDate(100.0)` function ([help entry](https://anylogic.help/advanced/functions/timetodate.html)).
2. Remaining time - create a function in the agent `f_getRemainingTime()` with this code:

```java
return dateToTime(p_dueDate) - time();
```

where `dateToTime()` will convert the `p_dueDate` value back into a double value representing simulation's time units and `time()` returns current simulation time (also as a double value).

so, let's say for a model starting on 1st Jan with time units = days; offset of 10 will result in `p_dueDate = 10th Jan` and on 3rd of Jan `f_getRemainingTime()` will return `7.0`.